# Flickr Gallery API wrapper for Python?

Tags: python, wrapper, flickr

Is there currently a Flickr API wrapper for Python which includes working with galleries?

I'm aware of these two wrappers, but neither of them seems to support galleries:

http://stuvel.eu/projects/flickrapi
http://code.google.com/p/flickrpy/

Is there some wrapper hidden away in the dark corners of the internet or would I have to write my own for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are none at the moment. It would be a good idea to write one of your own.

Comment: Thanks! I can't really mark as accepted, though, because it's not really an answerable question.

Comment: Yes, This answer would be incorrect and outdated, when you develop and publish the flickr gallery API ;)

Comment: Luckily the Flickr API is straightforward -- although reinventing the wheel, I just implement my own for the more basic features.

Answer (score 0):

The first one you mentioned (https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi) is written in a dynamic way, and thus supports all FlickrAPI methods, including the gallery functions.